# how compile some part of android os in windows?

Tags: java, android, compilation, operating-system

i want customize android setting and launcher for special device,i search and found that setting and launcher are separate application that can compile it, but when import setting project (from android os source code) in eclipse, it not compiled and has many errors that says can not resolve many imports as

```
import com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils
import android.hardware.display.WifiDisplay
import android.hardware.display.WifiDisplayStatus
,
...
```

i know above imports is hidden in android system and application developers can not access it, but i don't want compile hole android source in linux , instead of i want compile the following app (setting and , ...) and replace it in android image file ,
i work in windows platform and don't want migrate to linux and hate work with command line.

is it possible?

Comment: So you are working out of AOSP?

Comment: yes i want find shortcut to work in windows

Comment: Well I never compiled a AOSP application from Eclipse... I always built the whole thing from command line... Not sure you can use Eclipse to build only one AOSP application like that.

Comment: so it is not possible?

Comment: I did not say it was impossible, just not that I know of - and I told you how I did. But someone else might help you more over SO I hope.

Comment: can't you use some android emulator? if not, you could use a Virtual Box. and one last comment, you can never be a true programmer if you hate command line.

Comment: can tell me how i can see preview of change in android source code without flash image to device

Comment: nafas, I believe when we can do something with a few click why i must keep in mind a lot of commands

Comment: how i can run android image in emulator , my android image is allwinner rom image ?

Comment: how google compiled this project and which IDE used for it?    http://uupload.ir/files/6e3o_android.jpg